# MVC app redirects to error page after login and I have no idea why

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an MVC app that requests the user to login with his microsoft account, and it works fine when tested on localhost, however when publishing it to Azure, after logging in the user gets redirected to `http://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/home/error`, which causes a 404 not found since I haven't implemented an error method on my home controller. My problem though is I have no idea what causes the app to redirect to this error page. Trying to enter `http://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/home` manually on the browser just redirects to the error page again.

I tried creating a error method on the home controller that simply showed a "hello" on the screen and something really strange happened, the app kept redirecting back and forth between the error page url and the windows login page, without actually opening either (I could see the urls switching back and forth on the browser but neither page ever opened because it redirected before it finished loading).

I then left the methods on the home controller basically empty as you can see below, with only the default stuff added there by Visual studio remaining, but the same issue kept happening.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

On the web.config I had `<customErrors mode="Off"/>`, so I right clicked on the error page and clicked show source, and after the html there was this Exception stack trace listed there:

```
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;Error&#39; was not found on controller &#39;LogDatabaseApi.Controllers.HomeController&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

But this simply seems to say that the error method in the home controller was not found, it doesn't say why the app redirected to the error page in the first place. I actually have an API controller (that doesn't require authorization) in the same web app that is working perfectly. And the home controller works perfectly on localhost, it just does all this weird stuff on Azure.

**EDIT: Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private string resourceEndPoint = "https://manage.office.com";
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private string authority = aadInstance + "common";
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                        // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;

                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, resourceEndPoint);

                        AdminLogin.AdminOrganization = new Organization
                        {
                            Id = Guid.Parse(tenantID),
                            Name = "Unknown",
                            AccessToken = result.AccessToken,
                            TokenExpiration = result.ExpiresOn.DateTime,
                            RefreshToken = result.RefreshToken
                        };

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your routing look like? What happens if you navigate to `/home/index`?

Comment: @DavidG  As i said in my post, manually entering the /home adress on the browser redirects to /home/error. In my `RouteConfig.cs` I have `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Comment: Well how is your authorisation set up? Do you have an Azure database connected too?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I have an Azure database connection. My authorization set up is basically the default one created by VS when creating a multi tenant project with the "read directory" option enabled to generate tokens for the graph API. I added the startup.auth.cs class file to the post.

Comment: So your auth is failing somewhere, you need to debug that. You can see that in the `AuthenticationFailed` delegate where it redirects to `/home/error`

Comment: @DavidG Well, that's the biggest problem, when debugging on localhost everything works, including the authentication process, the issue arises only after publishing to Azure. Thankfully removing the `[Authorize]` from the home controller displayed a different error page showing that it was an issue with OWIN not detecting the correct startup class.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently OWIN was not detecting the startup class correctly and throwing an exception that caused the whole issue. Adding `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` to the appsettings in the web.config file solved the issue